# WCF POST failed in Fiddler Web Debugger

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, fiddler

I'm trying to test WCF service POST method using Fiddler tool, I tested GET using the same tool and its working okay.

Here is WCF implementation of POST method:

```
  [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "testpost/{test}")]
        string PostTest(string test);
```

Here is the Fiddler tool screenshot how I'm testing it, But getting HTTP 404 error:

**> Is it possible Opearation Contract WebInvoke has some problems ?**

here is the URI I'm testing http://localhost:50327/Service1.svc/testpost

[image]

Comment: The UriTemplate you have defined is set up to provide the 'test' parameter from the URL, but you are sending it in the body of the request.  If you do a POST against "Service1.svc/testpost/Working".  You should then see your method get passed the text "Working" in the parameter.

Comment: Thanks that is working with URL, what are the changes required if I want to send request in the body ?

Comment: I haven't run any test yet, but I believe if you just remove the '{test}' from the end of the UriTemplate in the code, you should be able to post almost exactly what you're doing in the screenshot and have it work.